# red5 server port 1935 closes after a few seconds - ubuntu 13.04

Tags: ubuntu, red5

I'm having a bad time with this red5 installation.  Port 1935 keeps closing on me after a few seconds.  The ofla demo fails.  port tester fails.  There are no firewall rules blocking 1935.  Has anyone else run into this problem?  I'm trying to get cometchat to work using my own Red5 server.

Thanks in advance!

Here's the result of my telnet session with the log spitting out onto the console:

root@me:~# telnet localhost 1935
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
[WARN] [Red5_Scheduler_Worker-2] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPConnection - Closing RTMPMinaConnection from 127.0.0.1 : 47327 to null (in: 0 out 0 ), with id 1 due to long handshake
Connection closed by foreign host.